# MacOS Monterey and SAP Commerce / Hybris 1905: Cannot start hybrisserver.sh

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm not able to start hybrisserver.sh on my MacOS Machine with 12.0.1. Ant all / build was successful, but after hitting ./hybrisserver.sh, I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

The files are available...

[image]

...and I should have full access to the path / file, at least the information window shows it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: At some step you probably run a command as root, now you can't start the server. Make sure you install every thing with your user and not as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very common issue on MAC. Please go to System Preferences --> Security Preferences --> General --> allow the blocked script here. Here you may be asked to allow the script to run a couple of more times. Then you will be able to start the server. Hope its helps.